How to fix scaling of Windows Forms application on a new PC
I changed my PC, and I setup all the apps like Visual Studio, DevExpress etc. with the same version as before.
After that I run the application on Visual Studio (the program is a Windows Forms application with C# code), there is a problem with scaling.
Normally I chose Windows state "maximized", but on my new PC, when I start the software in Visual Studio, the scaling of the Windows and fonts is so small. How can I fix this?

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%23+scaling+for+different+resolutions turns up dozens of existing questions about this same issue. Please do a thorough search before posting a new question here. It's part of the effort we expect users to put in before resorting to asking here.

You are true. I searched. But the difference of my issue that;
When i publish the app no problem. It is working fine.
But while I am working with the codes in the background of the program, I encounter a size problem when I run it in Visual Studio to see it. I can not find anything about this problem

Did you try holding down control key while turning mouse wheel?

I think, i can not tell myself completely. You can see the cituation in this picture https://i.hizliresim.com/3jjrlbq.png

I solved my problem with this codes on program.cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Technopat_Sosyal_Test_Program{
    internal static class Program{
        /// <summary>
        /// Uygulamanın ana girdi noktası.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(){
            if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6) { SetProcessDPIAware(); } // Windows Vista ve üzeri olduğunda çalışır.
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool SetProcessDPIAware();
    }
}


Glad to know your problem has been solved! See Can I answer my own question?  Just a reminder :)
